# How to take User Inserted values of Dynamic Table from html to PHP

Tags: php

I am new in php.I made and html Dynamic Table on which there are 2 following fields that are dynamically generated
for each time the user presses Add/Remove Button:

Image Sample given below:

[image]

Here the html Code given below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         table, th, td {
         border-collapse: collapse;
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         function addMore() {
             var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
             var row = table.insertRow(-1);
             var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
             var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
         
         var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[1].cells;
            
             cell1.innerHTML =  x[0].innerHTML;
             cell2.innerHTML = x[1].innerHTML;
         }
         
         
         function removeLast() {
             document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(-1);
         }
         
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form  action="data.php" method="post">
         <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
               <th>Options</th>
               <th>User Input</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <select class="mySelect" name="DESCR" >
                     <option  disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
                     <option  value="1">A</option>
                     <option  value="2">B</option>
                     <option  value="3">C</option>
                     
                     
                  </select>
               </td>
               <td> <input type="text" name="ALAMT"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         
      </form>
      <br>
      <button onclick="addMore()">Add New</button>
      <button onclick="removeLast()">Remove</button>
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
   </body>
  
</html>
```

After choosing option and inputing vaules to this table,i want to submit their data to php using `$_POST[ ]`
Because they are Dynamic,it will be time consuming  & inefficient to maintain unique  name or Id for each of
them.So,What code should i write in php to do so.please let me know for any further information.Thanks

Comment: I can suggest you to build a JSON model of your dynamic table and post it to your php script

Comment: Thanks @Inurosen for your info.is there any benefit doing it in JSON ? I don't know JSON, can you give some easy useful example to do so.Thanks

Comment: The benefit is simple. JSON basically is a javascript object and it's easiest way to build it.

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6631854/4577762) help you in any way? Also, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040540/post-with-variable-number-of-inputs)

Comment: I did this echo $_POST["myName"];.But  did not work.any clue.Thanks @Inurosen

Answer (score 1):

You Have to Take array as name of the new added field everytime. and that find the array count and make loop and get the value and put that value in the insert query.

used this script to add whole the textboxes

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.add_more').live('click', function () {
                $(this).before('<div class="one del"> <div class="two"><label class="label" for="name">Title:</label><input type="text" class="validate[required]" value="" name="caption[]" /></div><div class="two"><label class="label" for="name">Value:</label><input type="text" class="validate[required]" value="" name="values[]"/></div><i class="fa fa-trash-o add_del"></i></div>');
            });
            $('.add_del').live('click', function () {
                $(this).parent().remove()
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Then

```
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['caption']); $i++) {
        $caption = $_POST['caption'][$i];
        $sp_values = $_POST['values'][$i];

    $sql1 = "INSERT INTO `sub_project` (`parent`, `sp_title`, `sp_values`) VALUES ('$insert', '$caption', '$sp_values')";
        $insert1 = $obj_db->sqlquery($sql1);
```

}

Hope this help you